# Can I Use an IP Address in a SRV Record?

Tags: networking, dns, network-programming, devops, srv

I'm trying to understand whether or not is it possible to use an IP address in a SRV record's "Target" section instead of an hostname.

I noticed that when querying an SRV record (using `dig` or `dnsjava`) on a DNS server I'm getting the resulted hostname following a trailing dot (absolute path) - this means that if I want to use an IP address I'll have to chop the dot, so I'll be able to connect to targeted IP.

Is this follows the SRV's specification ([RFC 2782](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2782.txt)) ? And if I'm obligate to use a hostname, can you please explain why ?

I'm asking this for being able to implement the client side which fetch the result for a certain service after querying the relevant SRV record.

Answer (score 8):

The RFC you reference defines "Target" as:

> The domain name of the target host.  There MUST be one or more
>           address records for this name, the name MUST NOT be an alias (in
>           the sense of RFC 1034 or RFC 2181).

Therefore the target cannot be an IP address.

Comment: Thanks @Rob. I've noticed it but this quote sounds too blur for me. I'm looking for a solid justification for not being able to use it...